# nagios 302 Found - string not found

Tags: http, nagios

I am trying to monitor sites using nagios but I like this answer
who can help me rsvp

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H www.medcom.com.tn -I @IP -s "Tunis"
HTTP CRITICAL: HTTP/1.1 302 Found - string not found - 421 bytes in 0,105 second response time |time=0,105379s;;;0,000000 size=421B;;;0
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please consider rewriting/explaining it well.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning a 302 redirect, which is certainly not going to contain your string "Tunis".

To achieve what I think you want, add "-f follow" to your command to have check_http follow the redirect and check the actual content page.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is indeed not so clear. But as far as I can see from your command, you're trying to check if the string Tunis is available on the website www.medcom.com.tn
The check returns an [HTTP 302 status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) which is a sort of a redirection.
You should check out [the manpage on check_http](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http) on how to use this plugin correctly for your needs.